# Storing an array of formatted names in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm having trouble with my assignment and I've been scratching my head at it for a long time now. This is the criteria-- 
Your EmployeeNames class needs to have a static method named `convertName()`.
The method should accept an `array` of last names as the input parameter.
The method should return an `array` of formatted names(first and middle initials and last name).
For each element, it should determine the first initial and middle initial of the name and format it correctly (ex, H. T. Smith)
It should store each of these formatted names as elements in a formatted names array.

### After processing all the names, the method should return the formatted names `array` back to the calling program.

This is my code:

```
public class EmployeeNames {
    String[] names;
    public static String convertName(String names) {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            names[i] = names.substring(names[i].length - 2, names[i].length);
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

It's not even working right now, as I'm receiving the '`array` required, but `java.lang.String` found' error. But even after that, I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

> I'm receiving the 'array required, but java.lang.String found' error.

You have a global variable called `names` but *also* a variable called `names` in your method parameters.

Because they have the same name, `names` in your method parameters is hiding the global variable `names`. Since your method parameter `names` is declared as `String` instead of `String[]` it's throwing that error.

### The fix

To solve your issue, remove the global `names` and change the parameter `names` from `String` to `String[]`.

After which you'll notice that you should also change:

- The return type from `String` to `String[]`
- `names.substring` to `names[i].substring`
- `names[i].length` to `names[i].length()` since that's the length method for `String`.

### Changed code

The code after the changes:

```
public class EmployeeNames {

    public static String[] convertName(String[] names) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            names[i] = names[i].substring(names[i].length() - 2, names[i].length());
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, just tried that-- removed the global variable and made String into String[] as you recommended. However, the error seems to persist.

Comment: @taramenon Is it the same error or a different error?

Comment: Actually, after seeing your revised code version, it works! I think I just missed one step. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

> After processing all the names, the method should return the formatted
>   names array back to the calling program.

You'll have to change the method to return `String[]` instead of `String`.

```
public static String[] convertName(String[] nameString) { ... }

                                              ^
                                              |

                     /* Note: I have changed it to avoid any confusions */
```

You'll also have to make `names` as `static`,

```
private static String[] names;
```

**Edit:** Thanks, @Mark for pointing out that method should also accept `String[]` instead of a single `String` object.

Comment: Just tried it, but the 'array required, but java.lang.String found' error is there, now along with an incompatible types error at the return code (String cannot be converted into String[]?)

Comment: I didn't realize that the name of your formal parameter is also `names`. Change it to something else like `nameString` etc.

Comment: The requirement also says that "*The method should accept an array of last names as the input parameter.*" which is why I believe the global `names` should be removed and the method parameter changed from `String` to `String[]`.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I missed that part. Will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.